# Merge Sort Implementation Not Working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to learn more about sorting algorithms. This is my merge sort implementation. Is there any problem with my algo. Believe i am missing out something.

```js
var arr = [1,5,3,2,4,78,3,2];

alert(mergeSort(arr));

function mergeSort(arr){
 var len = arr.length;
 var mid = Math.floor(len/2);
 var left = arr.slice(0,mid);
 var right = arr.slice(mid);

 if(len < 2) return arr;

 return merge(mergeSort(left),mergeSort(right));
}


function merge(left, right){
 var res = [];
 var lLeft = left.length;
 var lRight = right.length;
 var l = 0;
 var r = 0;

 while(l < lLeft && r < lRight){
  if(left[l] < right[r]){
   res.push(left[l++]);
  }else{
   res.push(right[r++]); 
  }
 }

 return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mergeSort (arr) {    
    if (arr.length < 2) return arr;

    var mid = Math.floor(arr.length /2);
    var subLeft = mergeSort(arr.slice(0,mid));
    var subRight = mergeSort(arr.slice(mid));

    return merge(subLeft, subRight);
}

function merge (a,b) {
    var result = [];
    while (a.length >0 && b.length >0)
        result.push(a[0] < b[0]? a.shift() : b.shift());
    return result.concat(a.length? a : b);
}

var test = [1,5,3,2,4,78,3,2];
console.log(mergeSort(test));
```

Comment: hi @rajan, thanks for the first reply. Can u explain your merge function. i do not catch the .shift() part.

Comment: a[0] < b[0]? a.shift() : b.shift()  //here we are pushing the element in the result array, The shift() method removes the first item of an array, and returns that item & also changes the length of an array.